# How jump to Widget Activity of Android's Setting?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, broadcast, cmp

I want to click a button to jump to AppWidget of Android's Setting with intent or broadcast, but i don't find Intent.ACTION_XXX to Widget Activity.I try ComponentName but i don't know which package can complete this action. if intent is can't complete this action, can i use broadcasting to complete this action?
Who can tell me how jump to the appwidget of android's setting? Thanks.

Comment: the widget means appwidget.I didn't find the intent.action or broadcast.

Comment: although you accepted AndyFaizan's answer, it's definitely not clear if you are talking about general Android settings or you appwidget's settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by Settings widget. If it's the Android settings screen that you want, this should do it.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS, 0));
```

Don't forget to vote up if you find this helpful ;)